# Username and password are always incorrect in my django AuthenticationForm

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-forms, django-templates

I'm trying to login user by his username and password, but when i'm trying to check form.is_valid(), it returns False. Errorlist contain error: "Please enter a correct username and password. Note that both fields may be case-sensitive.". When i don't specify my own post it's doesn't work either.

I was looking for typo, but didn't found any. In internet nothing helped me at all.
I tried switch form and it's fields, but error was the same.

`views.py:`

```
from django.views.generic import *
from django.views.generic import *
from django.contrib.auth.forms import AuthenticationForm
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate, login, logout

...
class RegisterView(CreateView):
    form_class = UserRegisterForm
    success_url = reverse_lazy('main:homepage')
    template_name = "accounts/register.html"

    def post(self, request):
        form = self.get_form()
        if form.is_valid():
            user = form.save()
            login(request, user)
            return redirect("main:homepage")
        else:
            print(form.errors)
            return redirect("accounts:register")

class LoginView(FormView):
    form_class = AuthenticationForm
    template_name = "accounts/login.html"

    def post(self, request):
        form = self.get_form()
        if form.is_valid():
            form.clean()
            user = authenticate(
                request, 
                username=form.cleaned_data["username"], 
                password=form.cleaned_data["password"],
            )
            login(request, user)
            return redirect("main:homepage")
        else:
            print(form.errors)
            print(form.cleaned_data)
            
            return redirect("accounts:login")
```

`forms.py:`

```
from django import forms
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model, authenticate, login
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm, AuthenticationForm

class UserRegisterForm(UserCreationForm):
    email = forms.EmailField()

    class Meta:
        model = get_user_model()
        fields = ['username', 'email', 'first_name']


    def save(self):
        self.clean()
        user = self.Meta.model(
            username = self.cleaned_data['username'], 
            email = self.cleaned_data['email'], 
            password = self.cleaned_data['password2'], 
        )
        user.save()
        return user
```

`login.html:`

```
<div class="wrap">
    <form method="POST">
        {% csrf_token %}
        {{ form.as_p }}
        <button type="submit">CONFIRM LOGIN</button>
    </form>
</div>
```

Comment: How did you *register* the users? Can you share the register view?

Comment: Can you add the Signup view? My guess is that you're saving password in database as raw strings, but the `authenticate` function hashes the password and fails to verify them.

Comment: You should use `set_password` method to save passwords and verify them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code snippets are all correct , but the way of saving the user's password is incorrect in the from via save method , the way you are saving the password , it saves the raw text form of the password to the database , if you want to check , just open your database and check the password fields , they are stored in raw text format ( exapmle : testing123) where as the django saves , retrieves , password using password hashing alogrithm of sha256 until and unless you have not specified it and its hashes to  pbkdf2_sha256... this format .

dont save user like this :

```
user = User(username = username , password = password , email = email)
user.save()
```

save like this

```
user = User(username = username , email = email)
user.set_password(password)
user.save()
```

Update your code snippet :

```
from django import forms
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model, authenticate, login
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm, AuthenticationForm

class UserRegisterForm(UserCreationForm):
    email = forms.EmailField()

    class Meta:
        model = get_user_model()
        fields = ['username', 'email', 'first_name']


    def save(self):
        self.clean()
        user = self.Meta.model(
            username = self.cleaned_data['username'], 
            email = self.cleaned_data['email'], 
        )
        user.set_password(self.cleaned_data['password2'])
        user.save()
        return user
```

This will do the required work.

Answer (score 0):

```
class UserRegisterForm(UserCreationForm):
    email = forms.EmailField()

    class Meta:
        model = get_user_model()
        fields = ['username', 'email', 'first_name']


    def save(self):
        self.clean()
        user = self.Meta.model(
            username = self.cleaned_data['username'], 
            email = self.cleaned_data['email'], 
        )
        # Set password with method is solution
        user.set_password(self.cleaned_data['password2']) 
        user.save()
        return user
```

Comment: Can't you just completely omit the override of the `save` method? Normally the `UserCreationForm` already handles this properly.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

The reason this does not work is because passwords are *hashed*, and your `UserRegisterForm` does not hash the password properly. There is however no need to override the `.save(…)` method. Django's [**`UserCreationForm`** <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/default/#django.contrib.auth.forms.UserCreationForm) already takes care of this properly, since it is a [**`ModelForm`** <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/modelforms/#django.forms.ModelForm), so:

```
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm

class UserRegisterForm(UserCreationForm):
    email = forms.EmailField()

    class Meta:
        model = get_user_model()
        fields = ['username', 'email', 'first_name']
    
    # no override of save
```